# Getting an object's assigned variable name from a value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

For object such as these with each have some unique value like an id:

```
const obj1 = {name:"John", id:"0"};
const obj2 = {name:"James", id:"1"};
const obj3 = {name:"Jessica", id:"2"};
```

How could I find out which object belongs to an id?

For example, I have the id "1" and the function should return me the object, obj2 in this case.

Comment: Objects do not have names.

Comment: The variable it's currently assigned to (which may be zero, one or many) isn't a property of the object. It's unclear why you'd need this, what the context is; maybe you should have those objects _in an object_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make an array out of your objects and search for your wanted index?

Just to give a few examples when we assume your *object* look like this:

```
const objects = [
    {name:"John", id:"0"},
    {name:"James", id:"1"},
    {name:"Jessica", id:"2"},
];
```

**[`<Array>.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**

```
objects.find((e) => e.id === "1");
```

```js
const objects = [
    {name:"John", id:"0"},
    {name:"James", id:"1"},
    {name:"Jessica", id:"2"},
];

const result = objects.find((e) => e.id === "1");
console.log(result);
```

**[`<Array>.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```
objects.filter((e) => e.id === "1")[0];
```

```js
const objects = [
    {name:"John", id:"0"},
    {name:"James", id:"1"},
    {name:"Jessica", id:"2"},
];

const result = objects.filter((e) => e.id === "1")[0];
console.log(result);
```

**[`<Array>.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```
objects.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.id === "1") ? curr : acc);
```

```js
const objects = [
    {name:"John", id:"0"},
    {name:"James", id:"1"},
    {name:"Jessica", id:"2"},
];

const result = objects.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.id === "1") ? curr : acc);
console.log(result);
```

**[`<Array>.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)**

```
let result;
objects.some((e) => e.id === "1" && (result = e));
```

```js
const objects = [
    {name:"John", id:"0"},
    {name:"James", id:"1"},
    {name:"Jessica", id:"2"},
];

let result;
objects.some((e) => e.id === "1" && (result = e));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects don't have names, and more than one variable or property can refer to the same object. So in the general case, no, you can't find "the" variable containing an object by an object property because there may be more than one (and because there isn't really a good way to find them).

If you put those objects in an array, you can easily find the object with `id = "1"`:

```js
const objects = [
    {name:"John", id:"0"},
    {name:"James", id:"1"},
    {name:"Jessica", id:"2"},
];
// To find it:
const result1 = objects.find(object => object.id === "1");
console.log(result1);
// Or more generally:
function findById(array, id) {
    return array.find(object => object.id === id);
}
const result2 = findById(objects, "1");
console.log(result2);
```

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) loops through an array calling your callback, and returns the first object the callback returns a truthy value¹ for (or `undefined` if the callback never returns a truthy value). (There could, of course, be more than one, but `find` returns just the first.)

---

¹ "truthy value" - JavaScript has the concept of values that convert to `true` or `false` when used where a boolean is expected, The ones that convert to `true` are called "truthy," and the ones that convert to `false` are called "falsy." The falsy values are `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, and of course `false` (also `document.all` on browsers, for complex historical reasons). All other values are truthy.

Answer (score 0):

You can place them in an array, then iterate over it searching over the field you want.